# Laravel Blade imprime valores desconhecidos

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.3

Faço uso do Laravel 5.3.

Tenho uma variável que retorna esta valor em um var_dump():

```
 array(3) {
  [1]=>
  string(5) "10:00"
  [2]=>
  string(5) "10:20"
  [3]=>
  string(5) "11:40"
}
```

Porém se eu der:

```
@foreach($variavel as $valor)
    <label for="{{$valor}}"> {{$valor}} </label>
    <input type="checkbox" id="{{$valor}}" name="horario[0][]" />
@endforeach
```

Ele imprimi isso:

```
<label for="10:00">10:00</label>
<input type="checkbox" id="10:00" name="horario[0][]" />
<label for="10:20">10:20</label>
<input type="checkbox" id="10:20" name="horario[0][]" />
<label for="11:40">11:40</label>
<input type="checkbox" id="11:40" name="horario[0][]" />
```

E se eu fizer:

```
@foreach($variavel as $valor)
    <label for="{{print $valor}}"> {{print $valor}} </label>
    <input type="checkbox" id="{{print $valor}}" name="horario[0][]" />
@endforeach
```

Imprimi isso:

10:00
**1**
10:20
**1**
11:40
**1**

Não entendo de onde pode vir este número 1 após cada valor impresso, pois se faço este *print* dentro das tags do **PHP** ele não aparece. O que poderia ocasionar isso?
Será que consegui ser claro?
ps.: entre o valor e o número 1 aparece o checbox?

Comment: Coloque todo o código do foreach

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda
@foreach($horarios_livres as $horario_livre)
      {{print $horario_livre}}
@endforeach
Se eu usar {{$horario_livre}} ele imprime o código HTML, isso: <input value="10:00" type="checkbox" name="horario[0][]"/>, ao invés disso: 10:00

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você está usando errado, no código o `{{ }}` é substituído ***para***:

```
<?php echo e($horario_livre); ?>
```

então o código correto seria:

```
@foreach($horarios_livres as $horario_livre) 
    {{$horario_livre}}     
@endforeach
```

sem a necessidade de colocar [print](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.print.php). Quando é colocado o [print](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.print.php) só para ter uma ideia, é gerado o código:

```
<?php echo e(print $horario_livre); ?>
```

sendo que a saída no final é um número **1** pelo fato de [print](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.print.php) retorna um inteiro, [exemplo online](http://ideone.com/s85JvY).

***Referencias:***

- [Blade Displaying Data](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/blade#displaying-data)
- [Blade - Control Structures](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/blade#control-structures)
- [print](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.print.php)

Comment: Então Virgilio, sei que {{}} subistitui o echo, como comentei em sua primeira resposta aqui. Mas acontece de exibir isso "<p>paragrafo</p>" e não isso "paragrafo"; Já com print funciona, mas aparece esse número 01 das trevas. Agradeço a atenção

Comment: Você quer imprimir uma tag html? @CleberMartins, Edite corretamente a sua pergunta, só lembrando, você está fazendo errado!

Comment: Fiz edição da pergunta e tentei ser o mais claro possível. Se ainda tiver dúvida posso tentar clarear mias. Valeu

Comment: @CleberMartins eu expliquei o motivo e o erro, ele imprime um como resultado satisfatório do print, mas ali não precisa usar print como esta explicado na resposta, tanto que você mesmo fez na pergunta o certo e o errado. O 1 é o retorno do print porque echo print "texto"; imprime texto1.

Comment: Certo. Vou usar as tags do PHP mesmo porque funciona como deve. Não considero forma errada e sim um recurso usar o print, já que o recurso padrão {{}} não retorna um valor satisfatório (está exibindo o HTML como texto). Agradeço de toda forma a tentativa.

Comment: @CleberMartins tem duas formas utilize `{!!$variável!!}` para html. Você precisa ler a documentação para entender como p framework funciona. A tentativa e a forma de.perguntar esta trazendo confusão de.entendimento. Espero que isso resolva